# Why IQueryable<string>.First() can not get first item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm using LINQ to get something from db and put it into `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.ProcessNames = db.myTable.Select(o => o.ProcessName).Distinct();
```

The `ViewBag.ProcessNames`'s item are `[0]="String1", [1]="String2", [3]="String3"`.

Then I use `First()` to get first string in `ViewBag.ProcessNames`, but it return `String2` to me:

```
string temp = ((IQueryable<string>)ViewBag.ProcessNames).First();
```

If I convert `ViewBag.ProcessNames` to `List()` first, the `First()` will get right string `String1` that I want:

```
ViewBag.ProcessNames = db.myTable.Select(o => o.ProcessName).Distinct().ToList();
string temp = ((List<string>)ViewBag.ProcessNames).First();
```

Why `IQueryable<string>.First()` can not get first string?

Comment: Using `First` without `OrderBy` means you can't predict which element will get returned - it's up to the database to give you any element. With `ToList` you get all element into memory, which might cause a different order.

Comment: you need sorted list.. without that.. first() will never get you consistent result

Comment: The EF'provided First and ToList.First generate *different* SQL queries: it is the result of these queries that is being observed. (The order is *not* changed merely by moving the result "to memory". The result/order is exactly as it was returned from the database.) A RDBMS can generally return data in any order - ie. picking the fastest query plan - without an explicit ORDER BY as the order of a SELECT is generally non-deterministic due to RA's relation to sets.

Comment: Here you can try this one

    `ViewBag.ProcessNames = new SelectList(db.myTable, "myTableId", "MyTableProcessName").OrderBy(m => m.Text).FirstOrDefault();`